# What is wrong with this simple stochastic gradient descent code?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to learn SGD using R sgd package. However, I cannot get this simple example right. What is wrong? (Note for SGD X*beta, all the numbers are postive, which means we will always predict 1)

[image]

```
library(sgd)
set.seed(0)
d=ggplot2::diamonds
d$price=ifelse(d$price>2500,1,0)
noise_idx=sample(nrow(d),nrow(d)/5)
d$price[noise_idx]= ifelse(d$price[noise_idx]==1,0,1)

glm.fit=glm(price~.-carat,d,family=binomial)

sgd.fit <- sgd(price ~ .-carat, data=d,
                 model="glm", model.control=binomial(link="logit"))

glm.p=model.matrix(price~.-carat,d) %*% glm.fit$coefficients
sgd.p=model.matrix(price~.-carat,d) %*% sgd.theta$coefficients

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(glm.p,50)
hist(sgd.p,50)
```